# update the formula in the cell if column value is stored in a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have these formula   `activesheet.cells(3,"C").Formula = "=F2"`

but i want the formula to be like these `activesheet.cells(3,"C").Formula  = "=lastcolumn2"`

So I found the last column of the 6th row

```
last_col = ActiveSheet.Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

last_col has `10` value in it.

I have inserted the formula like these

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(3,"C").Formula = "=" & last_col & "1"
```

but these inserts a value `"=101"` but not as the formula `"=J1"`(which is what i expected)
How do i make that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution will work provided you work with **R1C1** notation instead of **LC1**.

Here is another way to do this:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1).Formula = "=" & Cells(1, last_col).Address
```

Comment: +1 this works very nice :) Sorry for a similar answer, it didn't hit he until I wrote and submitted it all.

Comment: `Great minds think alike` (that the best translation I've found from a great french proverb, I hope it still makes sense in English :))

Comment: Makes good sense :) I hope niko gives you the accept since you were first to the punch ^^

Answer (score 3):

You can also use .Address when you grab the last_col (slight spin on JMax's answer - sorry I just realized it's similar enough that I should have just added a comment under his). If you don't want the absolute path (like J1 instead of $J$1), you can use:

```
last_col = Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address(False, False)
Cells(3, 3).Formula = "=" & last_col
```

Comment: Nice precision about absolute path

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own question, sorry but i just found the way to do it when i accidentally opened my pivot table report and tried these way and it works.

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1).Formula = "=R" & "1" & "C" & last_col
```

Hope these helps someone else but please let me know if there are any others way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your question or your answer.  This does not really matter if you are happy but I suspect you got the effect you wanted by luck.

The original formula was `activesheet.cells(3,"C").Formula = "=F2"`.  This has the effect of setting cell C3 to the value of cell F2.  If cell F2 is changed, cell C3 changes to match.

You want to set cell C3 to the value of the last used cell of row 2.  You first used:

```
last_col = ActiveSheet.Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

This sets last_col to the number of last used column in row 6.  You do not explain why you are looking for the last used cell of row 6 and not the last used cell of row 2 which is what you said you wanted.

last_col has a value of 10.  The expression `"=" & last_col & "1"` has a value of `=101` because Excel does not know you want `10` converted to `J`.

You say you are happy with:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1).Formula = "=R" & "1" & "C" & last_col
```

But this sets cell A3 to the value of the cell with row = 1 and column = the last used column of row 6.

Nothing I can find in your question or your answer suggests this is what you want.

If you want cell A3 set to the value of the last used cell in row 2 as it is at the time the macro is run use:

```
  Dim last_col As Integer

  With ActiveSheet

    ' Find the column number of the last used cell in row 2
    last_col = .Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ' Set cell C3 = Now value of last of row 2
    .Cells(3, "C").Value = .Cells(2, last_col).Value

  End With
```

If you want the value of cell C3 to change each time the value of the last used cell of row 2 changes use:

```
  Dim LastUsedCellAddress As String

  With ActiveSheet

    ' Find address of last used cell in row 2
    LastUsedCellAddress = .Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address
    ' Set cell C3 = Current value of last of row 2
    .Cells(3, "C").Formula = "=" & LastUsedCellAddress

  End With
```

I hope the above gives enough of an explanation for you to understand the effects of the different statements so you can get what you want today and in the future.

Comment: This answer repeats information in other answers.  They were sent while I was writing this so I did not see then until after I sent this.  Since there is extra information in this answer I will leave it.